# A big white space area is showing at the bottom of my ScrollView in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ScrollView` inside which a `ConstraintLayout`, inside the `ConstraintLayout` there is a `RecyclerView`.

The structure is like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My code populate a list of objects to the RecyclerView, no problem there. The only problem is there is a big white space area showing at the bottom of the `ScrollView` , I can't understand why? Could someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance!

(A problem with this result is that for example if I have only one object in my list, there is no need to scroll the view, but it is still scrollable with the big white space area at the bottom.)

Answer (score 0):

Lost the `ScrollView`, `RecyclerView` can scroll on its own.

Also match_parent is not supported by `ConstraintLayout`

You need to constraint all sides to the parent and have 0dp (match_constraint) for width and height

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Notes

Your `ConstraintLayout` has `match_parent` for width and height.

You `RecyclerView` has `0dp` for width and height, which means to match the constraint, and your `RecyclerView` is constraint to all sides to the parent.

You recycler view will scroll when content is more that fits on screen

Comment: Could you please update the code snippet with the corresponding element? Is it for <ScrollView> or <ConstraintLayout>?

Comment: updated answer, check please, added explanation as well

Comment: No, with this , the whole view is not scrollable. I managed to fix the issue by using wrap_content for RecyclerView instead of match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

After using `wrap_content` instead of `match_content` for `RecyclerView`, my problem get solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ConstraintLayout bug (when wrapping a ConstraintLayout in a ScrollView) and was fixed in the new beta release. I had the same issue and updated to **1.1.0-beta4** and that solved it. Check here for latest releases:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/group-index.xml